# How take a snapshot or make a video of your device screen when your app is in background mode programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, snapshot

How to take snapshot of your device screen when app is in background **programmatically**. Or how to make a video of your device screen when app is in background.
Maybe it's possible to make using private api, so tell me them, please.

I want to make an app that will record your device screen using or not private api without jailbreak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is however not possible through apple's public/documented APIs and if through private APIs you were able to achieve the same then you will not be able to submit it to AppStore.

Comment: I don't want to send this app to the app store. I want to use it for my self to record video from apps that has my device for presentations.

Answer (score -1):

In the xCode organiser, if you have joined the Developer program, you can connect your device, and take a screenshot from there. Attach your device, go to Organiser and click on your device. There will be a section in the list called screenshots - run your app, then click on 'new screenshot' in the bottom right.

If the app is running on the device, pressing the home and top buttons briefly will capture a screenshot you your photos - you can them do what you want with them, or import them using iPhoto.

If you haven't signed up, you can take a screen shot from the iPhone / iPad simulator by pressing command-shift-4 in OS X, drag out an area of the screen you want to snap, and it will do so.

You can take videos of the screen using quicktime. See here: http://thenextweb.com/apple/2011/01/15/how-to-record-quick-easy-screencast-videos-with-mac-osx/

Comment: have you even read the question? read it again (How to take snapshot of your device screen when app is in background "programmatically")

Comment: I did read the question Sam, it has been edited since to make it more clear. The word programatically wasn't there. But thank you for taking the time to make me feel bad.